# Flexible vspace

Tags: spacing, paragraphs

I created a macro to insert diary-like right-aligned paragraphs.

```
\newcommand{\diarydate}[1]{\begin{flushright}\textit{#1}\end{flushright}}
```

Example:

```
\diarydate{New York, August 1992}
```

[image]

This looks great at the top of the page, but not if there's a paragraph preceding it. Therefore, I want to add vertical spacing before the diarydate text if it is located between two paragraphs, but not when it's at the top of a page or right after a heading.

Is there an easy command or macro that covers all those use cases?

Comment: use `\addvspace` space added by `\addvspace` is merged, if the section heading adds some and this ads some you get the maximum, not the sum

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks, but in this case I don't want the maximum. Rather, I want the diarydate not to add any space at all when following a heading.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to use a sectioning command, that will guarantee that no page break will be taken between the diary date and the following text. For instance

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[pass,showframe]{geometry} % to show the page frame
\usepackage{lipsum}
\makeatletter
\newcounter{diary} % to keep LaTeX happy
\newcommand{\diarymark}[1]{} % ditto
\newcommand\diarydate{%
  \@startsection{diary}%
    {10}%        level for secnumdepth and tocdepth
    {\z@}%       indentation
    {\topsep}%   space before
    {\topsep}%   space below
    {\raggedleft\normalfont\itshape}% format of the text
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\lipsum[2]
\diarydate{New York, August 1992}
\lipsum[2]
\section{A section}
\diarydate{New York, August 1992}
\lipsum[2]
\section{B section}
\lipsum[2]
\newpage
\diarydate{New York, August 1992}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

The space in the case of `\section` followed by `\diarydate` is the same as the space between a section title and normal text.

If you change the "space before" line into

```
    {-\topsep}%   space before
```

the first line after `\diarydate` will not be indented. I used `\topsep` as it is the vertical space used by `flushright`.

Here are the pictures.

### First page

[image]

### Second page

[image]

---

If you really want to suppress vertical spacing after a heading, you can do it in two steps:

```
\makeatletter
\newcounter{diary} % to keep LaTeX happy
\newcommand{\diarymark}[1]{} % ditto
\newcommand\@diarydate{%
  \@startsection{diary}%
    {10}%
    {\z@}%
    {\topsep}%
    {\topsep}%
    {\raggedleft\normalfont\itshape}%
}
\newcommand{\diarydate}{%
  \par % ensure vertical mode
  \if@nobreak % we're after a heading
    \vskip-\lastskip % suppress the space added by the heading
    \vskip-\topsep % suppress the space added by \@diarydate
  \fi
  \@diarydate}
\makeatother
```

and use `\diarydate` as before.

Comment: Thanks for the extensive answer. What I don't understand: Why do you define a diarymark command, but never use it? Also, pdflatex complains about "Illegal parameter number in definition of \diarydate". If I add a `[1]` parameter count, another error message pops up: "LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item"

Comment: The necessity for `\diarymark` comes from the use of `\@startsection`. I get no error with either version.

Comment: thanks, it was an error on my side :) It works great now (although I use `7mm` as space before, instead of `\topsep`.

Comment: Is there a way to prevent the items showing up in the table of contents?

Comment: @DaniloBargen Add `\newcommand\l@diary[2]{}` before `\makeatother`

Comment: Thanks, I just saw your edit when I wanted to post a minimal example :) Works now.